# tkinter definition with click button

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I try to let one of my definitions click a button of my GUI to run another definition:

```
def1():
    #### I don't know the code here

def2():
    print("Hello World")

window = Tk()

button1 = Button(window, text="click 2nd button", command = lambda: threading.Thread(target=def1).start())
button2 = Button(window, text="2nd button", command = lambda: threading.Thread(target=def2).start())
```

This is just a simple example, I can't run `def2()` directly in `def1()`, because the first and the second definitions take much time and I use threading to let both definitions run simultaneously.
I need something like `click(button2)` in `def1()`.

Comment: Do you know that you can call two functions, like `lambda: [print('First'),print('Second')]`.

Comment: Do both functions need to complete execution before proceeding further? If so, why not just have the button link to a single function that creates 2 threads and calls both the functions 1 for each thread?

Comment: The first function has to run for around 10-15 sec first, before the second function is able to start.